# Recommendations: Best Approach for simple file sharing app

Tags: development-environment

Background:

UxD designer with no application development background, some experience with HTML/CSS creation, quick learner

Wants to build:

- Simple file sharing application
- User credentials required for access
- Files will belong to one of a pre-determined category list
- Files will be 2-5KB in size each (application should prevent uploading of larger files)
- Users should be able to upload file and associate it with the appropriate category (overwriting existing files should not be supported)
- Users should be able to browse all categories and download any file
- Users will all be on Windows 10
- Would like to leverage freely available file repositories (Google Drive, Dropbox, etc)
- Application can be either desktop (Windows 10) or web-based (no hard-requirement .. just looking for the best/easiest option)
- Future considerations: Community-based features. Ability to add file descriptions/comments/rankings to each uploaded file

Here are my questions:

1. What development platform(s) would be most suitable for the above objectives?
2. Is it possible to utilize Google Drive or Dropbox as a centralized file repository for this type of application?
3. What other considerations might I have overlooked?
4. What are the biggest limitations/show stoppers in creating the type of application I have described?

Comment: One consideration is that services such as Dropbox have licensing limits on how many users can share the same free account. As far as platforms, Dropbox provides a collaborative feature for teams called Dropbox Business that would fulfill your requirements

Comment: Thanks @André I was hoping to be able to put a simple front end to this for a few reasons:  (a) don't want to give direct access to file repository  (b) hoping this will alleviate licensing limits (the front end would act as a single "user" into the repository ... (c) want to evolve into more front-end functionality ..   would something like JavaFX be able to read/write to Dropbox or Drive in this way?